# What can I do to give out the right object through ajax that is into a for loop

Tags: ajax, for-loop

The problem is that the FOR goes ahead while the ajax call retrieves the data from the URL, so only the last element into the array take the datum.
How can I synch the for with the ajax call, in that case?

```
   for(ii in scope.selMovies){
        for(jj in scope.selMovies[ii]){

            var title = scope.selMovies[ii][jj].title.replace(/\s*\(.*/, "");
            var yearMovie = scope.selMovies[ii][jj].title.match(/\(.*(20|19)[\d]{2}/)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

            http.jsonp(url + "&query=" + title + callb).
                success(function (data) { console.log( ii, jj, title, data.results );
                    for (k in data.results){
                        if(data.results[k].release_date.substr(0, 4) == yearMovie ) {
                            scope.selMovies[ii][jj].infoes = data.results[k];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            );

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `console.log(ii, jj, title, data.results)` always display the last `ii` and `jj` and `title`?

The problem is not that the for loop goes ahead while Ajax call call retrieves the data. The problem is that your `.success` callback function of `http.jsonp` is a closure within a loop, so it doesn't behave quite as one would naively expect.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for better understanding of what is going on.

To fix your specific case, do the following:

```
function MakeSuccessFn(scope, ii, jj, yearMovie, title){
   return function (data) { 
     console.log( ii, jj, title, data.results );
        for (k in data.results){
          if(data.results[k].release_date.substr(0, 4) == yearMovie ) {
            scope.selMovies[ii][jj].infoes = data.results[k];
            break;
          }
        }

   };
}
```

Then within the loop, change your `http.jsonp` to the following

```
http.jsonp(url + "&query=" + title + callb)
.success(MakeSuccessFn(scope, ii, jj, yearMovie, title));
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises in AngularJS are async so that for working with bunch AJAX requests is better to use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to handle all the responses after answering all the requests.

Comment: could you give me an example? please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a closure around your ajax call to encapsulate the values that are changed with every loop iteration at the point the Ajax call is made. Try this:

```
for(ii in scope.selMovies){
    for(jj in scope.selMovies[ii]){
        var title = scope.selMovies[ii][jj].title.replace(/\s*\(.*/, "");
        var yearMovie = scope.selMovies[ii][jj].title.match(/\(.*(20|19)[\d]{2}/)[0].replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
        doAjax(ii, jj, title, yearMovie);
         }
}

function doAjax(count1, count2, title, yearMovie) {
    http.jsonp(url + "&query=" + title + callb).
        success(function (data) { console.log( count1, count2, title, data.results );
            for (k in data.results){
                if(data.results[k].release_date.substr(0, 4) == yearMovie ) {
                    scope.selMovies[count1][count2].infoes = data.results[k];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```